# A question on submetrizable space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a submetrizable space. Then is $X^2$ still submetrizable?

> Recall that a space $X$ is called submetrizable if there exists a continuous injection of $X$ into a metrizable space.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f:X\to M$ is a continuous injection into a metric space, then $f\times f:X\times X\to M\times M$ is a continuous injection when $M\times M$ is endowed with (for instance) the metric $d((u,v),(s,t))=\max \{d(u,s), d(v,t)\}$.